# How to use SharedPreferences and Injectable in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection, sharedpreferences

Im using the library Injectable for Dependency Injection in flutter but Im getting a error where I cannot use SharedPreferences.

*Error:
Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized.
If you're running an application and need to access the binary messenger before `runApp()` has been called (for example, during plugin initialization), then you need to explicitly call the `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` first.
If you're running a test, you can call the `TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` as the first line in your test's `main()` method to initialize the binding.)*
I've tryed creating a class and put @lazySingleton

```
  Future<SharedPreferences> get prefs => SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

and I tryed to put WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()

```
void main() { 
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  configureInjection(Environment.prod);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 7):

you can pre-await the future in `SharedPreference` by annotating with `@preResolve`

```
@module
abstract class InjectionModule {

//injecting third party libraries
   @preResolve
   Future<SharedPreferences> get prefs => SharedPreferences.getInstance();
}
```

and on the `configureInjection` class

```
final GetIt getIt = GetIt.instance;

@injectableInit
Future<void> configureInjection(String env) async {
 await $initGetIt(getIt, environment: env);
}
```

and also on the main class

```
void main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 await configureInjection(Environment.prod);
 runApp(MyApp());
}
```

To actually use:

```
final prefs = getIt<SharedPreferences>();
await prefs.setString('city', city);
```

NOT:

```
final module = getIt<InjectionModule>();
module.prefs.setString('test', test);
```

Note differences between `SharedPreferences` and `InjectionModule`.

Comment: Just do remember to use it like this: final prefs = getIt<SharedPreferences>();
          await prefs.setString('city', city);  .... not getIt< InjectionModule >()

Answer (score 0):

Below is the way i got it to work, no guarantee it's the best method.

Await the configureInjection method in the main method.

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await configureInjection(Env.prod);
  runApp(App());
}
```

And wrap you app in FutureBuilder that makes use of getIt.allReady().

```dart
Widget build(context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: getIt.allReady(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        // ... your app widgets
      } else {
        // ... some progress indicator widget
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Helpfull links:

- https://pub.dev/documentation/injectable/latest/#registering-asynchronous-injectables
- https://pub.dev/packages/get_it#synchronizing-asynchronous-initialisations-of-singletons